# iOS VPN DNS leak

Tags: ios, dns, networkextension

I am experimenting with iOS Network Extension that does DNS over HTTPS. It is VPN for a single DNS IP address. VPN announce some IP as DNS.

It works. `res_ninit` shows I have 1 DNS that I have specified for VPN.

But when I turned off DnsOverHttp server I expected DNS resolving to stop to work but just thinks longer like 2-3 seconds vs instant resolving. Everything still work.

Sites like http://www.whatsmydnsserver.com/ print that I have my original my ISPs DNS.

If I start DOH server again then after some time iOS starts resolve domains via DOH.

Could you point me to some documentation that tells how DNS on iOS works or how to ensure default DNS is not used as it is DNS leak.

Answer (score 1):

When the DOH server connects to a host(IP/domain) the system might be using ISP's DNS.

Comment: What does it mean connects? I have coded extension. It was running while I was testing.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same kind of issue.

This issue was fixed from changing the VPN configuration from split tunnel to full tunnel.

In case of split tunnel if DNS resolving was slow it start leaking DNS requests.
But in case of full tunnel it never Leake any DNS request